# ERROR ITMS-900158 while submitting application on itunes

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, url-scheme, itmstransporter

ERROR ITMS-900158:"The following URL scheme found in your app are not in the correct format: [here](http://luvit.symphony-software.com/components/com_luvit/paypal/luvit.php). URL schemes need, to begin with, an alphabetic character and be comprised of alphanumeric characters, the period, the hyphen or the plus sign only. Please see RFC1738" for more detail.

Please help me with this issue as I'm not getting where I'm going wrong.

Comment: That link is expired now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**i Found my answer**

i was just making mistake by entering **CFBundleURLSchemes** values in an array it should be string

**correct format :**
[Please refer the image url for the correction made]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT5k7.png)

Answer (score 0):

URLScheme which represent the protocols you app responds too (like your-app://) and are defined in your Plist file under the key `CFBundleURLTypes`should not be an URL

Comment: yes its defined in plist , and in CFBundleURLSchemes you can provide with the URL thanks for the answer but you are mistaken.

Comment: **i Found my answer**

i was just making mistake by entering **CFBundleURLSchemes** values in an array it should be string
   
**correct format :**

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
   <string>com.symphony.luvit</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <string>http://luvit.symphony-software.com/components/com_luvit/paypal/luvit.php</string>
  </dict>
 </array>